# cakephp 3 how to export .xls files using cakephp 3

Tags: excel, cakephp-3.0

I'm new in cakephp 3 and i'm looking to export xml files

Can some one tell me how to do it?

```
// export function in controller to generate xls files
public function export() 
{
    $data = [
        ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        [1, 2, 3],
        ['you', 'and', 'me'],
    ];
    $_serialize = 'data';

    $this->viewClass = 'CsvView.xls';
    $this->set(compact('data', '_serialize'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHPEXCEL](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Keep this in Vendor, Import it and then use as explained in the Documentation on the Link provided.

Comment: thanks for the answer i fellowed the steps but i'm getting al ways an error  require(C:\wamp\www\qualite2\qualite\src\View\Helper\PHPExcel\Autoloader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP/View\Helper\PHPExcel.php, line 32]
Code Context
if (!defined('PHPEXCEL_ROOT')) {
    define('PHPEXCEL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) );
    require(PHPEXCEL_ROOT . '\PHPExcel\Autoloader.php');

Comment: The project has moved to https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel a long time ago, and just "_keeping it in Vendor_" is not the proper way of installing it, it should be installed via composer.

Comment: The project has moved into [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet).